# How to configure Grafana-flow-agent to connect to Grafana Mimir in river language?

Tags: grafana-agent, grafana-mimir

I have installed Grafana-flow-agent in a linux machine as per the documentation provided. However, there are no appropriate steps/documentation provided for Grafana-flow-agent configuration.

**Can any one help me on how to configure the Grafana-flow-agent to Grafana-Mimir in distributed mode in Open source ?**